# ASP.NET MVC 4 Error Handling

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-4

Okay, so I am trying to get my controller to go to the `Error.cshtml` under the `Shared` folder on error. I've got the filter configured at startup:

### Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    ...
}
```

### FilterConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

### HomeController.cs

```
[HandleError(View = "Error")] <---- I have the HandleError attribute
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IDbConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // get the users current events
        try
        {
            ViewBag.UserEvents = _connection.Query<MyEvents>("select ...)", new { });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpException(500, ex.Message);
        }

        return View();
    }
    ...
}
```

And so when the `Index` method is throwing an exception because I didn't open the connection, it just gives me the default ASP.NET exception page. What did I miss here?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the HandleErrorAttribute when using HandleError as a global filter.

Comment: I mean, you don't need the `[HandleError]` attribute on your HomeController when using `HandleErrorAttribute` as a global filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you by any chance running this on your local machine?  HandleError by default doesn't show errors on the local machine if you have customErrors set to Off or RemoteOnly.  Set it to On.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed, and I also pulled the attribute as you suggested!